# Query two tables and combine results based on created_at

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I have two tables, `cities` and `towns`.

What I need to do is query these two tables, combine their results, and order them by their `created_at` columns. Additionally, I need to limit it to a total of 25 results. I also need to somehow distinguish which record belongs to `cities` and which belongs to `towns` when displaying them in my view.

This is what I have at the moment, but I don't think it's the right way of doing it:

```
$cities = City::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
    ->get();

$towns = Town::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
    ->get();

$results = array_merge($cities->toArray(), $towns->toArray());
usort($results, function($a, $b)
{
    return $a['created_at'] < $b['created_at'];
});

return $results;
```

The problem with this is that it doesn't limit it to a total of 25 results. I'm also not sure if it's the best way of doing it.

The second problem I need to solve is displaying the results in my view. I need a way to distinguish which record belongs to which table.

In my view, I have something like:

```
@foreach ($results as $result)
    @if (CHECK IF RESULT IS CITY)

    @else (CHECK IF RESULT IS TOWN)

    @endif
@endforeach
```

How can I check which record belongs to which table?

Comment: Is there any relation between City and Town?

Comment: The only relation is that the `towns` table has a `city_id` column if the town is near or within a larger city.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

merge the 2 collection results then order them by date descendigly then take 25

```
$cities = City::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
    ->get();

$towns = Town::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
    ->get();
$merged = $cities->merge($towns);
```

then sort them

`$sorted = $collection->sortByDesc('created_at');`

finally take 25

```
$results = $sorted->take(25);
```

if you want to know which model the object is you can use native `is_a` [function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-a.php)

```
@foreach ($results as $result)
    @if (is_a($result, \App\City::class))

    @else (is_a($result, \App\Town::class))

    @endif
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure if this will work or not because I haven't tested it, But I feel it should

```
$cities = City::orderBy('id', 'desc')->limit(25)->get();

$towns = Town::orderBy('id', 'desc')->limit(25)->get();

$citiesAndTowns = $cities->merge($towns)->sortByDesc('created_at')->take(25);

// or use sortBy('created_at') for ascending....
```

Now in the view you can simply do it this way...

```
@foreach($citiesAndTowns as $cityOrTown)
  @if(get_class($cityOrTown) == 'App\City')

  @else

  @endif
@endforeach
```

Or to skip that dirty way of doing things, you can do `$citiesAndTowns->toArray()` and make changes in the view like this...

```
@foreach($citiesAndTowns as $cityOrTown)
  // Since `city_id` will never be a part of city table and even if
  // it is null in Town, it will still be set....
  @if(isset($cityOrTown['city_id'])) 

  @else

  @endif
@endforeach
```